# How to set the DocumentRoot while using python's HTTPServer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, httpserver

I have the following code as my python server:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

port = 8080
host_name = "localhost"
httpd = HTTPServer((host_name, port), CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
print("server started, to quit press <ctrl-c>")
httpd.serve_forever()
```

How do you set the DocumentRoot to which the server is serving the pages from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The built-in [`CGIHTTPRequestHandler`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/http.server.html#http.server.CGIHTTPRequestHandler) class serves from the current working directory, which is normally the directory from which you invoked Python.

> This class is used to serve either files or output of CGI scripts from the current directory and below.

You can use [`os.chdir()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir) to change the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

When you handle the GET request, you need to translate that into a path relative to the current directory the script is running in.

Look at http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html#module-SimpleHTTPServer and the **do_GET** section. You should be able to adapt that for your purposes

Comment: The link is broken.